# Is there anything to stop a subject access requester from being barred by a business?

Tags: gdpr, data-protection, private-property

A an access requester requests security footage of themselves from a business B. B services their request by providing the footage. But then wishes not to serve them again in the future. Is this lawful to refuse future service in apparent retribution for exercising data protection rights?

Comment: I can't find explicit laws or examples, but it would be against public policy to allow discrimination for exercising legal rights. The main issue wouldn't be whether a party is allowed to terminate or refuse a contract, but whether this would discourage exercise of rights. However, the GDPR only has explicit rules on such matters when it comes to withdrawal of consent.